# stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Could not determine which URL to request: Customer instance has invalid ID: <built-in function id>

Tags: python, api, flask, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to retrieve stripe user's stripeSubscriptionId & stripeCustomerId. Here's my code:

```
@blueprint.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"]) #confirms whether a user has subscribed or not
def stripe_webhook():
    payload = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    sig_header = request.headers.get("Stripe-Signature")

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, stripe_keys["endpoint_secret"]
        )

    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return "Invalid payload", 400
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return "Invalid signature", 400

    # Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if event["type"] == "checkout.session.completed":
        session = event["data"]["object"]
        # Fulfill the purchase...
        handle_checkout_session(session)

    return "Success", 200

def handle_checkout_session(session):
    subID = stripe.Customer.retrieve(id, status)
    logging.warn(str(subID))

@blueprint.route("/create-checkout-session")
def create_checkout_session():
    domain_url = "http://localhost:5000/"
    stripe.api_key = stripe_keys["secret_key"]

    try:
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            
            success_url=domain_url + "success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
            cancel_url=domain_url + "cancel",
            payment_method_types=["card"],
            mode="subscription",
            line_items=[
                {
                    "price": stripe_keys["price_id"],
                    "quantity": 1,
                }
            ]
        )
        return jsonify({"sessionId": checkout_session["id"]})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify(error=str(e)), 403
```

Yet I am getting: `stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Could not determine which URL to request: Customer instance has invalid ID: <built-in function id>, <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>. ID should be of type` str`(or`unicode`)`

I took doc as a [reference](https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-stripe-subscriptions/). However, I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve stripeSubscriptionId & stripeCustomerId from the webhook or in any other way for the past couple of hours despite reading all the docs. I have seen other SO pages but couldn't find one that had a similar concern as mine with a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    subID = stripe.Customer.retrieve(id, status)
    logging.warn(str(subID))
```

You're not getting the `id` anywhere here.  You likely want to use `session["id"]`.  Also I'm not sure what `status` is supposed to be there?

Comment: subscription status. I'll check the code rn. I assume subscription status should be `stripe.Customer.retrieve(session['status'])` or should it be just `session['status']`? Also, would that retrieve stripeSubscriptionId or stripeCustomerId, as I was wondering how to get both.